# javascript valiadtion is not working at the submit button

Tags: javascript

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <body>
   customer type:<input type="radio" name="customer" value="yes" onclick="return      check()"     checked="checked"/>yes
<input type="radio" name="customer" value="no" onclick="return check2()" />no

      <div id="one">
      firts name :<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required="required"/>
     </div>
     <div id="two" style="display:none;">
 Party Name<input type="text" name="party_name" id="pname" required="required"/>
    </div>

  <input type="submit" value="save" name="save" />
    </body>
       </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function check()
      {
         document.getElementById("one").style.display="";

   document.getElementById("two").style.display="none"; 

            }
  function check2()
     {
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";

    document.getElementById("two").style.display="";    

    }

         </script>
      </head>
    <?php
if(isset($_POST["save"]))
{

 header("location: hide_show.php"); 
   }


 ?>
```

here at the top are two radio buttons ...when i click on "Yes" radio button Div     one            shows and div two gets hide....when i click on "no" radio button then div two shows up and one hides ...now i have applied validation in both the textboxes so suppose if have choosen yes div one shows up and when i click submit button ...it doesnt get submitted because i have applied validation in div named two....valiadtion is also necessary...but is taking both div's validation at the submit time...plz suggest some way for this

Answer (score 0):

Try `style.display="block"` rather

```
function check()
{
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("two").style.display="none"; 

}
function check2()
{
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("two").style.display="block";    

}
```

Comment: its not working....at the submit time....with the validation of shown div...it is also asking for the validation of the hidden div....